# create buttons in java

Tags: android, eclipse, button, imageview

for an exercise I have to create some buttons. When clicked, these buttons should make appear an animated imagine. 
Can you helo to build the java code?
I just created the buttons and the ImageView, but I don't understand if I have to build one or two activity.
the buttons and the imageview have to stay in the same page: for example, when I click the "apple" button, the image view must show an apple, when I click "orange" it shows an orange, etc... all in the same screen.

my java code appear like this:

```
public class HomeWork extends Activity {

public static final int GET_CODE=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_work);

        Button getResultButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        getResultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent resultIntent =new Intent();
                resultIntent.setClass(HomeWork.this,HomeWork2.class);
                HomeWork(resultIntent, GET_CODE);
            }
```

but the onClick gives me an error

Comment: show your activity_home_work.xml and log

Comment: What are you trying to do at this line --> HomeWork(resultIntent, GET_CODE);

Comment: provide an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
>  Intent resultIntent =new Intent();
>                 resultIntent.setClass(HomeWork.this,HomeWork2.class);
>                 HomeWork(resultIntent, GET_CODE);
```

I don't cathes what are you doing in this. :)
if you need to open HomeWork2 Activity call

```
Intent resultIntent =new Intent(HomeWork.this,HomeWork2.class);
 startAcrivtyForResult(resultIntent, GET_CODE));
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I deleted the GET_CODE (I really don't know why I put it), and now my code appears like this:
ACTIVITY ONE:

```
public class HomeWork extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_work);

        Button getResultButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        getResultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent resultIntent =new Intent(HomeWork.this,HomeWork2.class);

                startActivity(resultIntent);
            }

        });
}
```

ACTIVITY TWO:

public class HomeWork2 extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_work2);

    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
}
```

ACTIVITY ONE LAYOUT XML

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:onClick="btn1_click"
    android:text="Apple" />
```

ACTIVITY TWO LAYOUT XML

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:onClick="btn1_click"
    android:text="Apple" />
```

no errors, but when I start the emulator, it give me the error "Unfortunately, Homework has stopped"
i watch in the logcat but I don't know what I had to change...